# Going back to the previous views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, subview

I am a newbie in iOS...
In my project i am navigating to other views using `addsubview`...

I have many views say 1 to 7..

`What i want is when i am on the 7th view or 6th view or 5th view i want to go back to the 2nd view on a button click..`

I am using **UINavigationController** example, but as far as i understood we can only go to the previous view...

I have used another example in which it takes me to the `root view`..
following is the code

```
   NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
```

So should i use a **UINavigationController** or do i need to use the above method with modifications??

Any ideas how can i achieve this..

Please Help!!!!

Thanks.

I am not using navigation controller currently but instead using addsubview method...
Is this a bad practice, do i specifically need to navigation control..
Thanks!!!

Comment: In general I'd suggest using a UINavigationController for that. However, if you have good reasons for not using a UINavigationController, such as the navigation bar that you may not want, then still consider separating your app into several view controllers, one for each major view, and present them modally.

Comment: I have 3 buttons and want them to be on all the view controllers... Just like a simple website where there is a logout button on each page.. Similarly i the 3 buttons are back,mainmenu and logout.. Each associated with its own function...

Comment: A navigation controller with a custom navigation bar could be a solution for that.

Comment: ok..Thank you..even i have a feeling the navigation view controller is a good practice ;) But i want to put the navigation bar at the bottom, any ideas??

Comment: @Audi: Check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866283/how-to-make-the-navigation-bar-of-an-uinavigationcontroller-display-at-the-botto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method of a navigation controller to move to a particular view:

```
popToViewController:animated:
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController%3aanimated%3a) for docs.

So if you have a `UINavigationController *navCon` and want to move to the second view use the below code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [navCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[navCon popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ok... Actually i have many views and each views i have a common footer ...That contains 3 buttons... each opens its associated view controller.. So i was thinking what is the best practice.. i.e. to use a navigation control or use the code given below and populate all views with 3 buttons..

Comment: @Audi:If whatever you require is given by both the method, UINavigationController way would be the preferred one , as far as practice is concerned. But what you want is entirely different from what `UINavigationContorller` offers then you can opt for other things.

Comment: But you can go a long way by just tweaking UINavigationController itself.

Comment: So considering my scenario what should i am for.... I was thinking about the tool bar... but still i have to add the toolbar to each and every view.. i.e. each xib file... I found a tutorial [link]http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/[link]  which customises the navigation controller

Comment: Sure go ahead and see what you get. :) I wouldn't be a good judge, especially without knowing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the 2nd view from 5th view use the below code:

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[allViewControllers removeObject:self];//removing 5th
[allViewControllers removeLastObject];//removing 4th
[allViewControllers removeLastObject];//removing 3rd
self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```

Now just pop the navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Please try following,

```
//This for loop iterates through all the view controllers in navigation stack.
for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

    //This if condition checks whether the viewController's class is MyViewController
    // if true that means its the MyViewController (which has been pushed at some point)
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]] ) {

        // Here viewController is a reference of UIViewController base class of MyViewController
        // but viewController holds MyViewController  object so we can type cast it here
        MyViewController *ObjmyViewController = (MyViewController*)viewController;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:ObjmyViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIViewController *viewcontroller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([viewcontroller isKindOfClass:[self.navigationController class]])
        {
            UIStoryboard *story_profile=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

            FindFriends_ViewController *objc_prof = [story_profile instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FindFriends_ViewController"];

            [self.navigationController popToViewController:objc_prof animated:YES];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sweet and Simple Solution :
 Just Write below code where your function is called:

```
- (IBAction)goToSecondViewController
{
   NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:i] animated:YES];
   // where i indicates viewController number,In your case write 2 instead of i.
}
```

Hope this might help you.