# Failing make Navigation Bar of an UINavigationController display at the bottom programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, cgrect

i am trying to make Navigation Bar of an UINavigationController display at the bottom.

[Put this in the viewWillApprear, it can work. But it go back to the top when come back via dismiss modal view from other views. Even this will be called again, it just stay on the top. So odd !](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5866389/1187845)

```
CGRect navBarOldCGRect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

CGRect navBarNewCGRect = navBarOldCGRect;
navBarNewCGRect.origin.x = 0;
navBarNewCGRect.origin.y = viewFrame.size.height - navBarOldCGRect.size.height -navBarOldCGRect.origin.y;
navBarNewCGRect.size.width = navBarOldCGRect.size.width;
navBarNewCGRect.size.height = navBarOldCGRect.size.height;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = navBarNewCGRect;


NSLog(@"viewFrame : %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(viewFrame));
NSLog(@"navBarOldCGRect : %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(navBarOldCGRect));
NSLog(@"navBarNewCGRect : %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(navBarNewCGRect));
NSLog(@"result : %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame));
```

Output of log like this;

```
viewFrame : {
    Height = 1024;
    Width = 768;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
navBarOldCGRect : {
    Height = 44;
    Width = 768;
    X = 0;
    Y = 20;
}
navBarNewCGRect : {
    Height = 44;
    Width = 768;
    X = 0;
    Y = 960;
}
result : {
    Height = 44;
    Width = 768;
    X = 0;
    Y = 960;
}
```

But not change on screen. Navbar still is still at the top of screen.

What is the point i am missing?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
bottomNav = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,  self.view.frame.size.height - 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0)];  
bottomNav.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;  
[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:bottomNav];
```

You can try to make like this

```
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      ..
                      nil];

    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
    self.toolbarItems = items;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5866347/1187845 allready saw this answer. did you tried or just copy/paste ?

Answer (score -1):

This is enough to create navigation bar. Put it on viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];

//New Answer

```
-(void) tabBarFunction
{
homeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
recentSearchBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myFavBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myOrderBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


    bgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 480);
    [bgImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
    [homeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 388, 80, 48)];
    [recentSearchBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 388, 80, 48)];
    [myFavBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 388, 80, 48)];
    [myOrderBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(240, 388, 80, 48)];




[homeBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_sel_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[recentSearchBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_unsel_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myFavBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_unsel_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myOrderBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"order_unsel_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[homeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(homeBtnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[recentSearchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(recentSearchTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myFavBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myFaveBtnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myOrderBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myOrderBtnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[self.view addSubview:homeBtn];
[self.view addSubview:recentSearchBtn];
[self.view addSubview:myFavBtn];
[self.view addSubview:myOrderBtn];

}
```

Comment: i don't get it. are you telling me, hide current navbar and create a new one?

Comment: navigation bar is always available. Our job is only do not hidden that.

Comment: but nav already there. at top of screen. i am tring to make at the bottom of screen.

Comment: Then you may use this code. See my code in answer.

Comment: I do not see any relationship between my question and your code. i already know adding buttons programmatically!